# In Kotlin almost everything is an expression and has a value

Tags: kotlin, output, return-value

I started to take a look at Kotlin programming language and there is something unclear for me and I would need some help to clarify it.

It is quiet clear for me, at a theoretical level, that in Kotlin almost everything has a value.
At a practical level it isn't and I found this case.

With this code:

```
val isUnit = println("This is an expression")
println(isUnit)
```

my output is

```
This is an expression
kotlin.Unit
```

so first it prints the value of `isUnit` and after that his type.

But if I'm doing that

```
val isUnit = 10
println(isUnit)
```

the output would be

```
10
```

Why in this case the output is not

```
10
kotlin.Int
```

?

Comment: in this example :
```val isUnit = 10
println(isUnit)```
'isUnit ' equal just 10 that in first example `isUnit ` equal function Unit
for same result you must write
```val isUnit = println(10)
println(isUnit)```

Comment: `This is an expression` is not a "value" of `isUnit` val, but a result of first `println`

Answer (score 5):

The `Unit.toString` is defined as:

```kotlin
public object Unit {
    override fun toString() = "kotlin.Unit"
}
```

And println changes Int type by the `String.valueOf(i)` in the end. And it returns the String representation of the value of Int.

You can print the name of the class using [KClass.qualifiedName](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/qualified-name.html):

```kotlin
val isUnit = 10
println(isUnit)
println(isUnit::class.qualifiedName)
```

Prints:

```kotlin
10
kotlin.Int
```

Comment: Yeah it's this - ``Int`` prints as its value because that's generally what you want to see. ``Unit`` is just a special "no value" object (similar to ``void`` in Java) so it just prints as its type name, because you might as well! Either way though, however it's printing, you're getting a value back from that expression in both cases